# Flutter project runs Android app but crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, crash, emulation, crash-reports

My Flutter project runs perfectly normally via an Android emulator, but when it comes to running it on iOS, it launches the app and immediately crashes. There aren't any problems shown in the debug console, and I've tried using Flutter Clean, updating cocoapods, and using different iOS versions. I am also using Firebase for my backend. Here is the problem report I get:

Image1:
[image: Image 1]
Image2:
[image: Image 2]

If there is any part of the crash report needed I can upload it as needed. I was expecting the app the run normally like its Android counterpart. Not too sure what the problem can be

Comment: There can be a million scenario can cause this , please provide a code so that you can get help